# New to Javascript. Can someone help me debug my program?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to implement a binary search in javascript and I'm completely new at JS. I'm mostly used to the C++ syntax, so it's been a little difficult for me to break any habits that I have.

When I include this script in an html doc, it fails to exit the script if the array size is less than 1 and doesn't trigger the array order alert if I enter an unordered array. In addition, the program never seems to finish the while loop, so I don't know if there are any other problems.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
var size = parseInt(prompt("Enter the size of the array:"));

if(size < 1) {
    alert("ERROR: you entered an incorrect value for the array size!");
    return;
}

var arr = [size];
var input = parseInt(prompt("Enter the numbers in the array in increasing order,"
        + " separated by a space, and press enter:"));

arr = input.split(" ");

var checkOrder = function(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if(!checkOrder(arr)) {
    alert("The values entered for the array are not in increasing order!");
}

var search = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number to search for in the array: "));

var lp = 0; //left endpoint
var rp = size; //right endpoint
var mid = 0;
var counter = 0;
var found = false;

while(lp <= rp) {
    mid = Math.floor((lp + rp)/2);
    if(arr[mid] == search) {
        alert("Found value " + search + " at index " + mid);
        counter++;
        found = true;
        break;
    } else if(arr[mid] > search) {
        rp = mid + 1;
        counter++;
    } else {
        lp = mid;
        counter++;
    }
}

if(!found) {
    alert("The value " + search + "was not found in the array");
    alert("I wasted " + counter + " checks looking for a value that's not in the array!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: An easy way to debug would be to use chrome debugger. Open your html file in chrome and press "Ctrl" + "Shitf" + "J". You can then put breakpoints in your script and see what might be going wrong.

Comment: I also recommend JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ for debugging

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [size];
```

The above code probably isn't doing what you want it to. This creates an array with *one* element, whose value is the value of `size`. You can create an array with a specific initial size by doing this:

```
var arr = new Array(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input method is not right.
Putting array initialization issue aside, the line

```
var input = parseInt(prompt(".."))
```

gonna give you one single number.

You can actually skip prompting for array size

```
var input = prompt('Space separated numbers:')
var array = input.split(' ')
if (array.length == 0) {
    alert('._.'); return
}
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = parseInt(array[i])
```